# Using multiple databases in Azure Redis using CLI

Tags: azure, redis

We are using Azure redis and would like to partition data into several databases. Note that we are using a single redis server not a cluster, so I am not talking about partitioning over servers.  I read that Azure Redis by default has 16 databases. Using StackExchange.Redis, I could programmatically set Keys in database 1 vs. database 0.

But when I use common redis CLI commands like CONFIG GET Databases it says unknown command. If I use SELECT xx (to select the database xx) and then issue Keys *, it still shows me keys for database 0.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: @Harsh Shah,  were able to find a solution to this?